# React Redux Thunk fetch: execute action based on result of dispatch / fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux, infinite-loop, redux-thunk

Using React & Redux & Redux-Thunk, trying to make this pseudocode:

```
    // pseudocode
    dispatch(makeServiceRequest)
    if failed
      dispatch(makeIdentityRequest)
      if successful
        dispatch(makeServiceRequest)
      end
    end
```

Want to avoid an infinite loop which would happen if the code was placed inside the `.catch` block of `makeServiceRequest`.

I'm using a `fetch(url).then(...).catch(...)` logic in the dispatch action.  `fetch` [does not reject on HTTP status errors](https://github.com/github/fetch#caveats).

How do I make this pseudocode happen?  What is the correct pattern to handle a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a `then` that checks HTTP status and throws an error if it isn't a success status just like it says in your link:

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response
  } else {
    var error = new Error(response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error
  }
}

fetch(url).then(checkStatus).then(...).catch(...);
```

Other than that, I'm not clear on what your Redux-specific question is.

Edit: based on your comments, I think you are asking how to manage a Redux actions that, when dispatched, can asynchronously dispatch other actions.  One way to model that is as a "saga".  There's a Redux library called [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/) that lets you model this sort of thing.

Comment: dispatch(makeServiceRequest) does the above `fetch.then.catch` code.  However, on failure, it should `makeIdentityRequest` and then try the `makeServiceRequest` again.  In your example, the failure lines would go in the catch, correct?  If so, the `makeIdentityRequest` & second `makeServiceRequest` would need to either be synchronous OR the second `makeServiceRequest` would need to be in the catch of `makeIdentityRequest`.  sync could mean infinite loop and in catch would be unintended behavior for the rest of the app.  AM I understanding that correctly?  Thanks.